# How to include whitespace but exclude any charater except number in regex mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, match

I have table like this

```
NO1                 | NO2
3173 02241016 0008 | 3673 0619 0590 0001
3173 0219 0312 1023 | 3671 1101 0380 0007
3173022701090232    | 3173 0218 0583 0006
3173 022601097060   | 3173 0214 0278 0010
3173021201121012    | 3173 0259 0694 1002
anywords any        | anywords any2
anyword2any2        | anywordsany3
anywords/ any-@       | anywords any2
```

I want to search the NO1 column if the value contain whitespace or any kind of seperated value like (\r,\n,\t) so i used this

```
select * from table1 where NO1 REGEXP '[[:blank:]]'
```

the result was

```
    NO1                 | NO2
    3173 02241016 0008  | 3673 0619 0590 0001
    3173 0219 0312 1023 | 3671 1101 0380 0007
    3173 022601097060   | 3173 0214 0278 0010
    anywords any        | anywords any2
    anywords/ any-@       | anywords any2
```

Now i want to exclude at least 1 kind of word except number but i don't know how to combine include and exclude inside a regex match query

```
    NO1                 | NO2
    3173 02241016 0008  | 3673 0619 0590 0001
    3173 0219 0312 1023 | 3671 1101 0380 0007
    3173 022601097060   | 3173 0214 0278 0010
```

How could i do that ?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  (Regexp changed in 8.0)

Comment: @RickJames mysql 5.7, what's change in 8.0 ?

Comment: "Character classes" changed.  In your situation, `[[:blank:]]` becomes `\s` (or, depending on client, `\\s`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want rows that consist of numbers at at least one blank.  A simple method is to fine any row that doesn't contain these characters:

```
where NO1 NOT regexp '[^[:blank:]0-9]' AND NO1 REGEXP '[[:blank:]]'
```

or:

```
where  NO1 regexp '^[[:blank:]0-9]+[[:blank:]][[:blank:]0-9]*$'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf6b0e2e745b4b4b9767f555fecece66) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: i got an error `> 1139 - Got error 'invalid character class' from regexp`, oh you missed the : part on blank

Comment: @Gagantous . . . Oops, it was missing the second `:`.  All fixed with a fiddle.

Comment: how could i do it vice versa ? i mean like `search the field if the value had at least one non-numeric character like alphabet, curly bracket. All of character other than number`

Comment: @Gagantous . . . That would be `where NO1 regexp '[^0-9]'` or something similar (you can add more characters that  you don't want between the square braces.

Comment: can i do it just like this ? `[^[:alpha:][:punct:][:space:]]`

Comment: whats the different if i do this just like this `^[^[:alpha:][:punct:][:space:]]*$` and like this `[^[:alpha:][:punct:][:space:]]` ?

Comment: @Gagantous . . . The first would match strings that do not have any of the mentioned characters, which would be an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
where  NO1 regexp '^[0-9]+[[:blank:]][[:blank:]0-9]*$'
```

is probably faster than Gordon's version.

This might be needed if you must avoid trailing whitespace:

```
where  NO1 regexp '^[0-9]+[[:blank:]][[:blank:]0-9]*[0-9]$'
```